# Android: Edit library and then update in project where i am using it

Tags: android, facebook, android-library

I am using com_facebook_android library in my project. I updated a file in com_facebook_android and then ran my project. The changes made to the library are not been reflected in my project. May I know the solution for the updating the library jar file so that the changes made to one of the files of the library are been reflected in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried rebuilding your library project?

In eclipse, right-click the project and click 'Build Project'.